# I don't understand why I've Statement::execute() error?

Tags: php, pdo

I've a error in my code but I do not find my error... Can you help me please ?
here is my code :

```
$updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs VALUES ('',:nom, :prenom, :email, :identifiant, MD5(:mdp)");

$updt->execute(array('nom'=>$nom,
'prenom'=>$prenom,
'email'=>$email,
'identifiant'=>$identifiant,
'mdp'=>$motDePasse
));

header('./gestion-utilisateur.php');</pre>
```

And this is the error :

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2 in...
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this will help you

```
$updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs VALUES ('',:nom, :prenom, :email, :identifiant, MD5(:mdp))");
// I think u missed one parathesis at the last thats it                                                    ^
```

Comment: Thank, indeed missing a parenthesis... So I've no error ! Only à little redirection problem with header.

Comment: Its pleasure helping you :) Yes it is not an error. may be we can call it a TYPO :D

Comment: Yes ;D 
I've i've another question, if can can help me (I am angry with objects...)
this is my code :
'          $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?');
          $stmt->execute(array($_POST['identifiant']));
          if ($stmt->fetchColumn() = 0)'

and here is my error :
'
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home/thibault/Documents/www/intra-stage-2.0/config/fonctions.php on line 281'

Comment: Where is the code?? What Question friend?? Don't be angry on Objects, make them friend. I'm sure u'll love it.

Comment: While comparing you should be using `==` and not `=` so your code will be `if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)`

Comment: This code is the condition for insert values in my table. Oh 
not the objects are not my friends, is the dark side of the code for me :p

Comment: I corrected the "==" but I submit my form, I've error "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" for this line '$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?');'

Comment: I think u need to post another question with all d code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
 $updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs VALUES ('',:nom, :prenom, :email, :identifiant, :mdp)");

$updt->execute(array('nom'=>$nom,
'prenom'=>$prenom,
'email'=>$email,
'identifiant'=>$identifiant,
'mdp'=>MD5($motDePasse)
));

header('./gestion-utilisateur.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
$updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs 
                         VALUES ('',:nom, :prenom, :email, 
                                 :identifiant, MD5(:mdp)");
```

I assume that the first field you pass `''` to is a auto increment field something like `id`.

Becasue you dont pass a field list to the query, you are also asking MySQL to work out what fields to add the data to automatically and it will do that by looking at the schema and getting field names for that table in the order they are stored in the schema. This can be dangerous as it is quite possible for someone else to change the order that they are stored in, in the schema.

So it is better to add the field names that you want to insert into the query.

MySQL will look after the auto increment field for you, but now it knows what fields it should be inserting data into from your VALUE list.

So use :-

```
$updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs 
                         (nom,prenom,email,identifiant,mdp) 
                         VALUES (:nom, :prenom, :email, 
                                 :identifiant, MD5(:mdp)");
```