# Why i've Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object?

Tags: php, pdo

I've ask a question for PDO error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135353/i-dont-understand-why-ive-statementexecute-error/25135509?noredirect=1#comment39126697_25135509)
But I've a another problem with object...

Here is my code :

```
include('../../config/connexion-bdd.php');

$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$regexNom = '/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/';
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$regexPrenom = '/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$regexEmail = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';
$identifiant = $_POST['identifiant'];
$regexIdentifiant = '/^[a-z1-9]+$/';
$motDePasse = $_POST['motDePasse'];
$confirmeMotDePasse = $_POST['ConfirmeMotDePasse'];
$regexMdp = '/^[a-zA-Z1-9]+$/';
$utilisateurConnecte = $_POST['utilisateur-connecte'];

if (preg_match($regexNom, $nom) && 
    preg_match($regexPrenom, $prenom) &&
    preg_match($regexEmail, $email) && 
    preg_match($regexIdentifiant, $identifiant) && 
    preg_match($regexMdp, $motDePasse) && 
    preg_match($regexMdp, $confirmeMotDePasse) &&
    $motDePasse == $confirmeMotDePasse)
    {
        $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['identifiant']));
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0){
               $updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs('nom','prenom','email','identifiant','mot_de_passe') VALUES (:nom, :prenom, :email, :identifiant, MD5(:mdp))");
               $updt->execute(array('nom'=>$nom,'prenom'=>$prenom,'email'=>$email,'identifiant'=>$identifiant,'mdp'=>$motDePasse));

               header('./gestion-utilisateur.php');
          } else {
              echo 'error 1';
          }
      } else {
          echo 'error 2';
      }
```

Therefore I have this error for this line `$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?');`:

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ...

Can you help my, please ?

Comment: `$bdd` doesn't exist. Presumably it's defined in `config/connexion-bdd.php` so you need to look in there to see where it's going wrong. Possibly it just couldn't connect to your DB.

Comment: Remove the quotes `('nom','prenom','email','identifiant','mot_de_passe')` those are columns, not values. [**Treat them as such**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all clear, Your `$bdd` is not containing a SQL connection. You have to check for the validity of the SQL connection.

`$bdd` must be an object, and thus it contains a method called `prepare()`.

When the connection is not established correctly, the variable `$bdd` will not be an object and thus will not have a method prepare.

Now, when you use `$bdd->prepare()` it throws an error that `$bdd` is not an object, thus it could not have a method called `prepare()`

Now, you should present a `var_dump($bdd)` before the `$bdd->prepare()` line for use to inspect it.

Comment: I tested var_dump($bdd) before prepare() and it returns me the name of my database. Furthermore my code after the condition `if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)` works very well !

Comment: You have stated you have error for `$bdd->prepare()`, if true then you cannot have the next line executed. You probably mean the error belongs to the line `$connect->prepare()` ?

Comment: No, I'm sure. Error saying that it is line 280 and my line 280 is `$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?');`... And I just retried my insertion in my table commenting this :

      ` // var_dump($bdd);
      //   $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?');
       //  $stmt->execute(array($_POST['identifiant']));
          if (/*$stmt->fetchColumn() == 0*/1==1)`

Comment: You should include your connections file. Is that MySQLi connection?

Comment: @Thibaulc *"Furthermore my code after the condition `if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)` works very well ! "* - You're saying that the INSERT `$updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs('nom','prenom','email','identifiant','mot_de_passe') VALUES (:nom, :prenom, :email, :identifiant, MD5(:mdp))");` works? I find that rather hard to believe, since the columns are wrapped in quotes.

Comment: In reality, this line does not work when it is written like this. I have the corrected this way to make it work : `$updt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateurs VALUES ('',:nom, :prenom, :email, :identifiant, MD5(:mdp))");`

Comment: I found the solution... it was an error variable ... Thanks for all !